# How do I add react-router support to my Rails 5 app using react-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, reactjs, react-router, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a Rails 5 app and am looking to learn/use React.js.

I was able to use gem 'react-rails' to build a simple React.js experience in my Rails app. Now I would like to add react-router to my Rails app however this doesn't seem to be as easy as I would expect. There is no gem for react-router that supports Rails 5, and there are no clear installation instructions for adding react-router to a Rails 5 app.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like many other javascript libraries, you don't necessarily need a gem for them to hook them onto your rails app. So try loading the javascript file for react-router so that it's usable in your react app.